# How can I use a branch other than master for User Github Pages

Tags: github, github-pages

Github pages is nice, but it requires that the static files you wish to show be in the `master` branch. This is problematic for me because I intend to generate the blog post files from source code, and that code is what I'd like in master. Github for Project pages uses a `gh-pages` branch. Is there some way I can tell github to use that branch for a User pages repo?

Comment: On the de-facto official bug tracker: https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/212

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this, as the required branch names are hard-coded into Github's pages implementation. One thing you could do is create a project page and treat it as a user page, which works even better if you [set up a custom domain](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/).

A simple workaround would be to create a branch with a different name and treat it as your master branch. It won't be named "master", but in the end every branch looks the same to Git anyway, so it's just an issue of semantics.

Comment: I feared this would be the case, but thank you nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-09-03-build-and-deploy-github-pages-from-any-branch/) Github blog post from September 2020, it is now possible to build and deploy from **any** branch :

> Repositories that use GitHub Pages can now build and deploy from any branch. Publishing to the special gh-pages branch will still work the same as it always has, but you can now choose a different branch in your repository as the publishing source. This functionality also removes the hardcoded dependency on user and organization pages having a master branch.

The instructions to do so are available in their [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-from-a-branch) :

1. Make sure the branch you want to use as your publishing source already exists in your repository.
2. On GitHub, navigate to your site's repository.
3. Under your repository name, click  Settings.
   [image: repo-actions-settings image from Github]
4. In the "Code and automation" section of the sidebar, click  Pages.
5. Under "Build and deployment", under "Source", select Deploy from a branch.
6. Under "Build and deployment", under "Branch", use the None or Branch drop-down menu and select a publishing source.
   [image: publishing-source-drop-down image from Github]
7. Optionally, use the drop-down menu to select a folder for your publishing source.
   [image: publishing-source-folder-drop-down image from Github]
8. Click Save.
   [image: publishing-source-save image from Github]